# Swift: crash at non-existing line

Tags: c++, swift, crash, ios13

Hey StackOverflow detectives.

I've been pulling my hair out for a few months trying to figure out the crashes which happen at a line never exists.

In the crash log below, CustomClass.swift **does** exist but the line 25 **doesn't**.

What would be the true reason for this crash?

Hint: we run heavy processing and allocate a lot of memory (about 700MB) in the background that was written in c++, which is in OUR_CUSTOM_FRAMEWORK below.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001934c6df0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001933e6930 pthread_kill + 228 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193374ba4 abort + 104 (abort.c:110)
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001933d7fdc malloc_vreport + 564 (malloc_printf.c:183)
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001933d81a4 malloc_report + 64 (malloc_printf.c:192)
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001933cbd1c free + 436 (malloc.c:1733)
6   [OUR_CUSTOM_FRAMEWORK]          0x000000010324ccf8 0x1031a4000 + 691448
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000193355164 __cxa_finalize_ranges + 416 (atexit.c:284)
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001933554a0 exit + 28 (exit.c:81)
9   UIKitCore                       0x000000019782eb88 -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 508 (UIApplication.m:6735)
10  UIKitCore                       0x0000000196f97718 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 128 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:765)
11  UIKitCore                       0x0000000196f9737c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer forceExitWithTransitionContext:scene:] + 220 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:418)
12  UIKitCore                       0x0000000197824ac4 -[UIApplication workspaceShouldExit:withTransitionContext:] + 216 (UIApplication.m:3725)
13  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019893bcf8 -[FBSUIApplicationWorkspaceShim workspaceShouldExit:withTransitionContext:] + 88 (FBSUIApplicationWorkspace.m:144)
14  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000198968d68 __83-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient willTerminateWithTransitionContext:withAcknowledgement:]_block_invoke_2 + 80 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:281)
15  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019894debc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240 (FBSWorkspace.m:357)
16  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000198968cf4 __83-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient willTerminateWithTransitionContext:withAcknowledgement:]_block_invoke + 140 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:278)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019338033c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:495)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001933830d4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264 (queue.c:466)
19  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019898f6c4 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48 (FBSSerialQueue.m:173)
20  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019898f370 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 432 (FBSSerialQueue.m:216)
21  FrontBoardServices              0x000000019898f8dc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32 (FBSSerialQueue.m:247)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019365baf4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1922)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019365ba48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 84 (CFRunLoop.c:1956)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019365b198 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:1992)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193655f38 __CFRunLoopRun + 796 (CFRunLoop.c:2882)
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001936558f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
27  GraphicsServices                0x000000019da6c604 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2246)
28  UIKitCore                       0x0000000197829358 UIApplicationMain + 1944 (UIApplication.m:4823)
29  [APPNAME]                       0x0000000100d45128 main + 68 (CustomClass.swift:25)
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001934d12dc start + 4
```

Comment: Is this optimized code, or unoptimized?  Optimized code can give "funny" call stacks.

Comment: yes, this is a crash report from a production build.

Comment: My best guess is that the application is failing during termination while it is deconstructing objects while multithreading.  Probably an object was already destructed `atexit`, but other objects during their destruction rely on the now destructed object, and then the application has a SIGABRT because everything is in the giggleweeds.

Comment: interesting. what are the options I can try? I'll definitely try building without optimization.

Comment: If my guess is correct, then it's a bit of a grind.  Order of construction and order of destruction problems are not fun to resolve.  And if it is a multithreaded race condition, those are worse.  If you can reproduce the problem with the optimized build (that has debugging information), that'll help a lot.  If you can reproduce the problem with a debug build, that'll even be better.  If you can't repro the problem under the microscope, then any fixes would be purely speculative.